# WPF Control and Window issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Hey all here is a noob question regarding WPF and controls.

I download the project called **[FluidKit](https://fluidkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README.txt)** which comes with a hand full of examples for **3D image effects** and just **image effects** in general.

Problem I am having is that I just want **1 type** of effect out of all of those but I am unsure how to go about making a new project and copy/paste the **FluidKit** code to my new project just for that needed effect. I am needing to be able to reproduce this a couple of times in my window and not just once as I currently have.

The code is for the following:

> TransitionTester.xaml

Which within that has a few settings like:

> Cube (Left to Right)
>
> Cube (Right to Left>
>
> Cube (Top to Bottom)
>
> Cube (Bottom to Top)
>
> Slide (Left to Right)
>
> Slide (Right to Left)
>
> Flip (Left to Right)
>
> Flip (Right to Left)

This **TransitionTester.xaml** looks to be a **UserControl**.

So I create a new WPF project and now I have the following forms:

> MainWindow.xaml
>
> TransitionTester.xaml

and of course I replace a **reference** to the **fluidkit.dll**.

Bow after copy/pasting the code from the fluidKit project to my new project I end up just having 2 errors which is astonishing to me!

The errors are:

> Error CS1061  'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'SwitchImage' and no extension method 'SwitchImage' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error      The resource "SlideTransition" could not be resolved.

My MainWindow.xaml code looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="flipwindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:flipwindow"        
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:FluidKit.Controls;assembly=FluidKit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Controls:TransitionPresenter x:Name="_transContainer"
                                      MouseLeftButtonDown="SwitchImage"
                                      RestDuration="0:0:3"
                                      IsLooped="True"
                                      Transition="{StaticResource SlideTransition}">
            <Image x:Name="_image1"
                   Source="Images/img1.png"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <Image x:Name="_image2"
                   Source="Images/img2.png"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <Image x:Name="_image3"
                   Source="Images/img3.png"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
        </Controls:TransitionPresenter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind that page looks like this:

```
namespace flipwindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string _backItem = "_image1";
        private string _frontItem = "_image2";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += TransitionTester_Loaded;
            //PlayCube();
        }

        private void TransitionTester_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _transContainer.TransitionCompleted += _transContainer_TransitionCompleted;
        }

        private void _transContainer_TransitionCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SwapFrontAndBack();
        }

        private void SwapFrontAndBack()
        {
            string temp = _frontItem;
            _frontItem = _backItem;
            _backItem = temp;
        }

        private void PlayCube()
        {
            CubeTransition transition = Resources["CubeTransition"] as CubeTransition;
            //transition.Rotation = Direction.LeftToRight;
            //transition.Rotation = Direction.RightToLeft;
            //transition.Rotation = Direction.TopToBottom;
            transition.Rotation = Direction.BottomToTop;

            _transContainer.Transition = transition;
            _transContainer.ApplyTransition(_frontItem, _backItem);
        }
    }
}
```

The second error listed above show up on this line:

> Transition="{StaticResource SlideTransition}">

While I am not sure about the first error and what it's looking for in order for that to be corrected. It seems to maybe be related to the **UserControl.Resources** that I can not seem to add to my Window:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Controls:SlideTransition x:Key="SlideTransition" />
    <Controls:CubeTransition x:Key="CubeTransition" Rotation="BottomToTop" />
    <Controls:FlipTransition x:Key="FlipTransition" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Layout looks like this:

[image]

And my **MainWindow.xaml Design** looks fine as well:

[image]

When comparing it with the **original FluidKit window**:

[image]

So any help to help me fix those 2 errors would be great!

**UPDATE 1**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First: the MouseLeftButtonDown tag refers to a callback function in your code behind which of course can not be found. So just insert the `SwitchImage` function as it is in the FluidKit original code in `TransitionTester.xaml.cs` to the `MainWindow` class code in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file which should have be created next to your `MainWindow.xaml` file. (Maybe keep it empty for testing purposes)

Second: Yes, you have to copy the `<UserControl.Resources>` xml code from the original xaml-File to your file. But you have to replace the tag `<UserControl.Resources>` by `<MainWindow.Resources>` as your surrounding tag is `<MainWindow>`. (The resource named `SliceTransition` which is referred to later in the code is defined inside this block)

Comment: i seem to only be able to do **<Window.Resources>** and not **<MainWindow.Resources>** as you suggested? I get an error of **'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'SwitchImage' and no extension method 'SwitchImage' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Comment: Any help with this @Fratyx?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you have to use <Windows.Resources>. The first part of the combined tag of course has to be the same as the embedding tag.